# WPF c# SendKeys to another Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to send Keys, from a WPF, to another Window (e.g. editor)

I found this Methode

```
public static class SendKeys
{
    public static void Send(Key key)
    {
        if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
        {
            if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
            {
                var e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Down) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, but it doesn't work :/

so I call it from my main program

> SendKeys.Send(Key.D7);

In this case is WindowsForms not an alternative :/

Comment: Why can't you use the [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System.Windows.Forms`? You can reference the DLL, you don't have to create a Windows Forms project to use it.

Comment: SendKeys.SendWait from winforms or inputmanager https://michlg.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/wpf-send-keys/

Comment: Ever since Windows Vista, one should not be using `SendKeys`.  Instead you might want to take a look at _Microsoft UI Automation_.  And no, it doesn't mean you need to write CodedUI tests

Comment: @ Ron Beyer this was the "Solution" ... Thanks ;)

Comment: Problem... => I press [Alt] + [1] to trigger the Keys... the Program recognize the [Alt]-Key ... I wrote a trigger who recognize the Release of the [Alt]-Key but the Tool also Recognize the [Alt] an do some (e.g. Menue-Actions) Faults (only after 300ms I can do "SendKey actions"). It is possible to Release the Alt Key on Software-Side or Ignore the Alt Key on SendKey?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` parameter passed instead of `Key.Down`.

This worked fine:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        this.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(Key.A);
        SendKeys.Send(Key.B);
        SendKeys.Send(Key.C);
        SendKeys.Send(Key.D);
        SendKeys.Send(Key.LeftCtrl);
    }

    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Key pressed: " + e.Key);
    }
}

public static class SendKeys
{
    public static void Send(Key key)
    {
        if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
        {
            if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
            {
                var e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent };
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this work only "local" ... If I sleep this Program and Switch to editor "no Keys" will press in the editor Window!